# Can someone help me close my account?

Tags: support

How do I delete my account? I don't need to use this account anymore. Besides, there are plenty of good sites that I can use. Stack exchange is too conversational for me. I need something more complete, organized and clear.

Comment: It's best to contact moderators privately, which you can do by flagging your own post and adding a message.

Comment: Have you considered simply not using this account? Then, if you decide you would like to use math.SE again, you can do so with the privileges that you have already earned.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you be a bit more explicit about what's troubling you?  Knowing this could help us improve the site.  Judging from your questions you seemed relatively pleased with the answers: "Thanks, this is super clear to me now", "Thank you, Nameless lifesaver!", etc.

Comment: "Besides, there are plenty of good sites that I can use"..
just out of curiosity, what are these sites?

Comment: @dwarandae http://wedoyourhomework.com/ comes to mind...

Answer (score 6):

You can request account deletion by contacting SE via the "contact us" form linked at the bottom of the page. There is an option for account deletion there. The direct link to that is

https://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion

As already said, you don't have to delete the account if you don't want to use the site anymore, but you are of course free to request deletion.

Comment: The page does not make it clear if the account is deleted from the particular site (math) or from the entire SE network. Do you know which one is it?

Comment: @5PM Generally only from the particular site, unless you request otherwise.